# Mkfifo in GNU Octave

Tags: octave

I have yet to find a complete example for using the `mkfifo()` function online. I am able to make the fifo like this:

```
mkfifo("file",777)
```

But when I `fopen()` this file, Octave just hangs.  What is the proper way to create, queue, and dequeue bytes from a `mkfifo` object?

I would like to create an in-memory fifo in Octave (on-disk is fine too) and read and write it from the same Octave script.  My project is running in real time, and so I need a buffer so that I can fill and drain from the same Octave script.  I've searched for a fifo library with zero results.  Even just creating a vector and pushing and popping will suit my needs.  I tried this myself, but I'm running into object oriented programming design problems because Octave does not allow pass by reference or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifo class works, but only up to a certain size.  The max size in bytes of a fifo can be found by running:

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size
1048576
```

Below is the code that I wrote for an in-memory fifo.  It's fairly crude but it works well:

```
1; % Prevent Octave from thinking that this is a function file

global fifoCount fifoSamples fifoFiles fifoFids fifoDataType
fifoSamples = zeros(0);
fifoCount = 0;
fifoFiles = cell(1);
fifoFids  = zeros(0);
fifoDataType = 'single';
fifoDataTypeSize = 4;
fifoMaxBytes = 1048576; % this is operating system enforced, changing here will not help

function [] = o_fifo_write(index, data)
    global fifoCount fifoSamples fifoFiles fifoFids fifoDataType

    wrcount = fwrite(fifoFids(index), data, fifoDataType);

    [sz,~] = size(data);

    fifoSamples(index) = fifoSamples(index) + sz;

    if( sz ~= wrcount )
        disp(sprintf('o_fifo_write was given %d samples but wrote %d', sz, wrcount));
    end

    if( ~iscolumn(data) )
        disp('data must be columnar in o_fifo_write');
    end
end

function [data] = o_fifo_read(index, count)
    global fifoCount fifoSamples fifoFiles fifoFids fifoDataType

    [data, rdcount] = fread(fifoFids(index), count, fifoDataType);

    [sz,~] = size(data);

    fifoSamples(index) = fifoSamples(index) - sz;

    if( sz ~= rdcount || sz ~= count )
        disp(sprintf('in o_fifo_read %d %d %d should all be the same', sz, rdcount, count));
    end
end

function [avail] = o_fifo_avail(index)
    global fifoCount fifoSamples fifoFiles fifoFids fifoDataType

    avail = fifoSamples(index);
end

function index = o_fifo_new()
    global fifoCount fifoSamples fifoFiles fifoFids fifoDataType

    fifoCount = fifoCount + 1;
    index = fifoCount;

    fifoSamples(index) = 0;
    fifoFiles{index} = tempname;
    [ERR, MSG] = mkfifo(fifoFiles{index}, base2dec('744',8));
    fifoFids(index)  = fopen(fifoFiles{index}, 'a+');
%     fcntl(fifoFids(index), F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);  % uncomment to avoid hangs when trying to overfill fifo
end


% ---- usage -----

txfifo = o_fifo_new();
disp(o_fifo_avail(txfifo));
o_fifo_write(txfifo, [1.243 pi 2*pi 4/3*pi]');
disp(o_fifo_avail(txfifo));
disp(o_fifo_read(txfifo, 4));
disp(o_fifo_avail(txfifo));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. First: mkfifo expects mode as integer with base 10, if you write "777" you think in octal, base 8. Second: mkfifo uses umask to modify the permissions to (mode & ~umask) (See man 3)

As example:

```
fn=tempname
[ERR, MSG] = mkfifo (fn, base2dec("744", 8))
stat(fn)
fn = /tmp/oct-83UCBR
ERR = 0
MSG = 
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

dev =  2053
ino =  3408172
mode =  4580
modestr = prwxr--r-- 
nlink =  1
uid =  1000
gid =  1000
rdev = 0
size = 0
atime =    1.4311e+09
mtime =    1.4311e+09
ctime =    1.4311e+09
blksize =  4096
blocks = 0
```

As you can see the modestr is now prwxr--r-- as you would expect from octal 744

Now you can open one end of the FIFO:

```
fid = fopen (fn, "r")
```

Of course this blocks until the other end of the fifo gets connected.

Comment: @portforwardpodcast: The "Octave hangs" is the expected blocking of fopen until the other end connects (because it's opened without O_NONBLOCK)

Comment: Yeah, a lot is unclear and missing.  According to this: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/filesize-of-fifo-td1613956.html I need to call `fcntl(fid, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); ` immediately after opening the file for reading.  But that line never runs because I am blocked when opening the file for reading before the writer gets there.

Comment: Just to be clear I need to read and write this fifo from the same script, I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: I got a bit lost doing this in Octave 6.4.0 on a raspberry pi. There using the octal conversion didn't work. I had to literally pass in 777 as the mode, and not do the conversion from octal. I'm not sure if this is a version of difference or because of the platform.